# How to remove /drupal from URL in Drupal 7 when installation is in the associated sub-directory

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-7

In Drupal 6 I was able to successful install Drupal in a subdirectory called drupal and then reference the site without having to use example.com/drupal.
In Drupal 6 to get this to work I did the following:
- Created an .htaccess file in the root directory where /drupal was created. The file contents was:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ drupal/$1
```

Updated the `drupal/sites/default/settings.php` file to have the $base_url defined as:
`$base_url = 'http://example.com';`

When I try and do the same thing for Drupal 7, only the front page can be displayed, all the pages fail quite horribly (or only display the front page). I have also tried uncommenting the RewriteBase lines in /drupal/.htaccess. First I tried `RewriteBase /drupal` and then tried `RewriteBase /`. But both attempts failed. I never needed to do this with D6, but I thought I would rule out this possible fix.

I am currently testing the new Drupal 7 install using xampp (version 1.7.4) with the example.com site under htdocs (i.e. xampp/htdocs/example.com/drupal). The Drupal 6 site is within the same xampp installation, but of course with a different directory path (e.g. xampp/htdocs/d6example.com/drupal). Note that I also have the Drupal 6 installation running on a production server with only the $base_url variable value changed.

So, how can you install Drupal 7 in a subdirectory and then run it from that directory without having the directory name in the URL?
Note I am installing Drupal 7 in a subdirectory as it allows for easier upgrading between new releases of the Drupal 7 core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /example.com
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/ [L]

# rewrite rules for drupal files
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example.com/drupal/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ drupal/$1 [L,QSA]

# rewrite rules for drupal paths
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ drupal/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Put this .htaccess file in example.com directory.
You don't have to modify drupal7 .htaccess

Comment: Unfortunately the above does not work in conjunction with changing the $base_url variable. In fact it is worse than what I had as it removes the Drupal theme formatting.

Comment: It works for me, try to add RewriteBase in this .htaccess and comment it in drupal .htaccess

Comment: Given that this is working for you, I wonder if it has to do with my install or modules which I have enabled. I have since disabled pathauto and cleared all the caches. But it has not helped.
Perhaps it is due to my use of xampp. Thus the RewriteBase / directive actually takes me to localhost (which in turn is directed to localhost/xampp/). I have tried RewriteBase /example.com, but this does not work either.
What I find really curious is that all this worked for Drupal 6, but does not work for Drupal 7. It makes me think that they changed something to effect this functionality in the core.

Comment: I should also state that I have a different site working within the same xampp installation using Drupal 6. Thus the only difference with the site that does not work is Drupal 7.

Comment: Please update your question to add details about your directory/path structure

Comment: You are a champion @soju!!! Your answer has worked. Thank you. :)
I must say, I am looking forward to D8 with the new /core directory. None of this stuffing around. Thanks again.

Comment: @soju, I did some testing on each line of the solution you provided, and it seems that the `RewriteBase /example.com` line is not required. Does this seem reasonable to you?

Answer (score 4):

On Apache server, add this to the root .htaccess file.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) drupal/$1 [L]

Update the drupal settings.php file (in /drupal/site/default/ directory) so that the $base_url line reads:

```
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question on this here:
[Two Drupal installation on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072167/two-drupal-installation-on-the-same-server/19218482#19218482)
My answer to your question is the same, I recommend eschewing the rewrite method in favor of the virtual host method as described below (which is just an excerpt of what I answered in the link above):

> ...
> To do this correctly you must first enter the following line (or un-comment the line if >it already exists):
>
> ```
> NameVirtualHost *:80
> ```
>
> Next you must create the two virtual host entries. One will be similar to the following:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName your.url.fortheroot
> ServerAlias alternate.url.fortheroot
> DocumentRoot "/path/to/webroot"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> The next entry would be similar to the following
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName your.url.forthesubfoldertest
> ServerAlias alternate.url.forthesubfolder
> DocumentRoot "/path/to/webroot/test"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> ...

In your case, however, you would only require one virtual host entry & not two.

Additionally, it should be noted that, should you desire to serve a site from a location NOT in your webroot then you would also need a

```
<Directory></Directory>
```

entry to tell Apache what access to give to visitors (NOTE: in Linux the Apache user should be made owner of the files [or permissions should be set in a method that still allows the apache user rights to serve the files if you want to avoid giving it ownership])