# Changing default install url path Bitnami Drupal 7 VM

Tags: drupal-7, bitnami

In the bitnami default install of drupal 7 I want to change http://example.com/drupal to http://example.com/content

First attempt: modify `$base_url` in settings.php (/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/default/)

This seemed to break the content at /drupal but did not change the location.

Second attempt: try editing the .htaccess file for everything (/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/).  I added RewriteBase /content. Not sure but this didn't seem to change anything.

Third Attempt: try editing the .htaccess for the site (/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/default/files) as described in this post:
[How to remove /drupal from URL in Drupal 7 when installation is in the associated sub-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716839/how-to-remove-drupal-from-url-in-drupal-7-when-installation-is-in-the-associate)

But I'm not even sure if I changed the example to the right thing.  Deep down I don't believe that this many config lines are needed to change this.

I'm on bitnami-drupal-7.12-2-ubuntu-10.10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the alias in the included apache conf file at `/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/conf/drupal.conf`

If you look at the file, you'll notice that the alias is set to `/drupal`
Change this to `/content`