# Two Drupal installation on the same server

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I installed Drupal 7 in the root folder of my server.
Now I would like to install another Drupal 7 website in a subfolder (/test), but when I run the /test/install.php script, I get:

"
To start over, you must empty your existing database.
To install to a different database, edit the appropriate settings.php file in the sites folder.
...
"

It seems that it is still loking at the database of the version in the root folder.

In /test/sites/default/config.php I set the new db.

I suspect that this is all related to .htacess and rewrite rules.
Somebody can help?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is old, however there is, in my opinion, a more thorough and lower risk option than creating a re-write rule to resolve this problem.
The alternate option for this situation is to use a virtual host entry in your .htaccess file.

In order to do this properly you must create two virtual host entries. One entry for the original URL/Drupal 7 install (the one @ the site root).
The second virtual host entry will be for a second URL which points to the Drupal 7 site in the subdirectory.

To do this correctly you must first enter the following line (or un-comment the line if it already exists):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Next you must create the two virtual host entries.
One will be similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName your.url.fortheroot
ServerAlias alternate.url.fortheroot
DocumentRoot "/path/to/webroot"
</VirtualHost>
```

The next entry would be similar to the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName your.url.forthesubfoldertest
ServerAlias alternate.url.forthesubfolder
DocumentRoot "/path/to/webroot/test"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you do not use the virtual host method and you choose the rewrite method there is a possibility that you may need to modify the settings.php to reflect the correct base root of your Drupal 7 install for the one in the /test subdirectory. 
(try without but if you have problems with clicking on links giving you 404 errors then try with).
NOTE: I still definitely recommend the virtual host path over the rewrite rule path.

Answer (score 0):

I performed a similar operation by having a sub folder installation of Drupal I used for staging purposes.

I added the following to my `.htaccess` of the original drupal installation to tell it to ignore my subfolder.  Otherwise the original installation will try to handle access to the subfolder installation.

```
#Place this right below RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/test/"
```